# query to select rows which have exactly same number of occurence with user id

Tags: mysql

I have a table active_users and want to show result which have only 2 records with same user_id and notified=0 (grouped into one)

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1247820/6b77352e2cd12aee951d6a092e919ca1

Above record should give no result

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1247822/0b3f2e5fac17d3cb2d559cb17bfa5e90

and this should give result

```
ID  user_id mobile   last_seen              notified 
1   25853   xxxxxx   14-May-2016 17:11:12   0
```

Comment: It's even the same database

Comment: it is a different question.I only want to display records which have  exactly 2 count    with same user_id.

Comment: So you really need an answer to explain how to replace ">2" with "=2"? Is that some homework assignment? Or are you both the same user?